# ¿Se debe decir jefe o jefa al referirse a una persona de sexo femenino?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género

Mi jefe en el trabajo es una mujer. ¿Cómo es la forma correcta de referirse a un [jefe](http://dle.rae.es/jefe) que es mujer?  ¿jefe o jefa? Algunos compañeros de trabajo le dicen jefa, yo le digo por su nombre sin embargo revisando en la RAE la definición de jefe viene lo siguiente:

> **jefe**.
>
> (Del fr. chef).

Ahora por ejemplo en la definición de doctor:

> **doctor, ra.**
>
> (Del lat. doctor, -ōris).

Como podemos apreciar en la definición de doctor viene indicado que tambien se puede usar como femenino (doctora) pero en el caso de jefe no viene. Tomando en cuenta esto, ¿es correcto usar el sustantivo femenino de jefe, es decir jefa?

Otro caso igual es "[presidente](http://dle.rae.es/presidente)" y "presidenta" donde tampoco viene indicado la forma femenina. Por ejemplo en el caso de Brasil donde el presidente es una mujer ¿es correcto decir "La presidenta de Brasil."?. ¿O en este tipo de sustantivos no es posible utilizar el femenino de ellos?

Comment: ¿Respeto, igualdad? Esas no son categorías lingüísticas, lo siento. La azafata y el azafato, bien, como también lo son la enfermera y el enfermero. Pero por favor quedémonos respetando las reglas de corrección gramatical y digamos tranquilamente presidente y dentista, que no presidenta y dentisto, por ejemplo.

Comment: No hay tal cosa como azafato, para masculino siempre es sobrecargo.

Comment: @Jaime *Sobrecargo* y *azafato* son cosas distintas. El término correcto para una azafata de avión, hoy día, es *auxiliar de vuelo*, igual para ambos sexos. *Sobrecargo* también se usa para ambos sexos, pero es un cargo distinto.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Puedes usar cualquiera de los dos.

Pero preferiría usar jefa, para evitar mal interpretaciones.

No sabes la sorpresa que uno tendría al ver que le dices "jefe" a alguien que es mujer.

Por ultimo y solo como etiqueta, seria mejor que le llames por su nombre.

Edito: Solo una observación [jefa](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=jefa) sí esta en la RAE. Igualmente [presidenta](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=presidenta).

Comment: Eso mismo pense y ya que ambos somos de Monterrey coincido contigo respecto a que se puede mal interpretar si se usa en masculino. Solo que me llama la atención como en la RAE no viene el sustantivo femenino.

Comment: Incorrecto, Jefa no existe, al igual que Jueza tampoco. Nunca he oido decir "La Jefa de la agencia", ni "La Jueza..."

Comment: @FrankComputer en España ambos términos se usan corrientemente en hasta un 80%, indudablemente están ya muy arraigados.

Comment: En un 80% no sé, pero [en auge desde luego sí está](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jefa&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: Es cierto solo que jefa y presidenta tienen su propia entrada a diferencia de doctor y doctora que comparten la misma. ¡Gracias!

Comment: No se de que país seas Frank, pero la RAE no es ningún mandatario en la lengua, ellos solo recopilan las palabras y hacen recomendaciones pero generalmente tienen que ceder en lo que consideran "incorrecto". Aquí en México hasta en los programas del gobierno está la palabra jefa. http://www.sedesol.gob.mx/en/SEDESOL/Seguro_de_Vida_para_Jefas_de_Familia

Comment: La palabra *jefe*, como *presidente* y otras, no aparece como *jefe, -a* porque eso significaría que el único femenino de *jefe* es *jefa*; sin embargo, al menos según la RAE, *jefe* también puede usarse como femenino. Por eso *jefa* tiene una entrada aparte. En mi experiencia (soy español), el uso muy mayoritario para el femenino de *jefe* es *jefa*.

Comment: Por otro lado, estoy de acuerdo con la consideración que hace @razpeitia en su respuesta: la palabra *jefe* (o *jefa*) no suele usarse como vocativo, al menos en España. Yo puedo decir *mi jefa es Marta Ramírez*; pero, para dirigirme a ella, la llamaré *Marta* o *señora Ramírez*, nunca *jefa*. Aquí, la palabra *jefe* se usa en determinados ambientes para llamar al camarero o al encargado de un local, aunque ninguno de ellos sea tu jefe ni tengas ninguna relación laboral con él.

Answer (score 8):

Respecto a “*presidente*” es el antiguo participo activo del verbo “*presidir*”. con el sufijo “-*ente*” (de entidad) que como “-*ante*” o “-*iente*” forma adjetivo verbales.

Otros adjetivos verbales son *ayudante, agobiante, gobernante, veraneante, absorbente, dirigente, dependiente, crujiente, ...*

Entonces, "*crujiente* " ¿es femenino o masculino? ¿Deberíamos decir "*el pan es crujiente*" pero "*las uvas pasas no son crujientas*"?

Cierto es que cuando estos adjetivos se sustantivan ("*el protestante*") en algunos casos se ha generado de forma natural una forma femenina ya plenamente aceptada por la RAE ("*la dependienta*") aunque no siempre se usa de forma consistente (se sigue usando "*la dependiente*").

Pero en la mayoría de los casos no es así (¿o alguien dice "*la estudianta adolescenta es una protestanta integranta del coro de la capilla ardienta*"?). Por  mucho que algunas feministas vean influjos machistas en algunas palabras terminadas en "-ente", en realidad son neutras, y se refieren tanto a *un ente* como a *una entidad*.

El caso de "*jefa*" es parecido, aunque no sea un adjetivo verbal, por cuanto es una feminización admitida por la RAE de "*jefe*" que deriva del barbarismo  "*chef*" (también admitido por la RAE) y éste a su vez del latín "*caput*" (cabeza en el sentido de cabezilla o capitán).

Pero "*jefe*" termina con la neutra "*e*". Y si vamos al origen, "*jefa*" no deriva de "*chefa*". Además, "*Chef*" es hoy una palabra de uso corriente y a nadie se le ocurre feminizarla. Es más, tampoco nadie diría "*el cabezo de familia*" ni "*la cabeza de familia*" (si habla de un padre,  ni "el cabezillo de los bandoleros". En cualquier caso son palabras que describen quién está al mando, no el sexo que tiene. Esto es más evidente cuando  emplea como adjetivo: la  "*jefa de enfermeras*" se convierte en la "*enfermera jefe*", (no en la "*enfermera jefa*").

Por tanto, por más que se admita "*la presidenta*" o "*la jefa*" y sea además la tendencia actual, lo más ortodoxo sería emplear "*la presidente*" y "*la jefe*".

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, una respuesta mucho más correcta que la aceptada.

Comment: @Bardo el problema con esta respuesta es que lidia con lo que _debería_ ser. En los idiomas siempre hay dos puntos de vistas; como las cosas son y como deberían ser. Para alguien que aprende español, lo segundo es irrelevante, para ellos lo importante es como el idioma se usa en realidad, cómo expresarse de forma normal y cómoda. La respuesta aceptada lidia con esto perfectamente.

Comment: @clich Si fuera como _debería ser pero no es_, de acuerdo, pero no son   expresiones medievales que ya no se usan. _La presidente_ sigue siendo válido y se entiende. Por otra parte, incluso si no se usa, saber como debería ser no es  irrelevante. Los niños hispanohablantes aprenden a conjugar verbos sin saber si realmente se usan o no , y por eso hay un momento en que conjugan sin pudor los verbos irregulares como regulares, pero parten de una buena base. En lo adultos pasa al contrario  y por eso entender los verbos españoles son la pesadilla de cualquiera que no conozca una lengua latina.

Answer (score 3):

Si está reconocida en el RAE la debes utilizar. Para aquellas profesiones todavía no recogidas es discutible su uso.

Tradicionalmente muchas de estos términos se utilizaban sólo en masculino puesto que eran varones quienes las desempeñaban. Al aumentar la presencia de la mujer en estas profesiones surge la discusión y muchos plantean la necesidad de introducir la forma femenina de dichas profesiones.

Sin embargo, empieza la discusión al darse la situación de que en castellano, el genero de las palabras no tiene porqué coincidir con el genero del objeto designado. Por tanto, estrictamente hablando, no sería necesario crear dichas voces PERO por una cuestión de respeto y de igualdad no está demás el considerar su introducción.

No es de más recordar que lo mismo sucede en sentido opuesto: suena mal decir "azafato" por el varón que realiza las funciones de asistente de vuelo. En este caso o bien se le designaría como azafata o, lo que finalmente se ha optado en España -en otros países sería aeromozo/aeromoza-, asistente de vuelo.

Comment: Sin embargo algo que me parece interesante es que existen palabras que no se pueden utilizar en femenino ya que suena mal por ejemplo "albañil" no podemos decir "la albañila" sería "la albañil".

Comment: ¡Correcto! Por eso hago notar que si aparece en el RAE conviene utilizar la forma femenina/masculina y sino dejarse llevar por el sentido común, lo que dice la calle y al mismo tiempo tratar de evitar herir susceptibilidades innecesariamente.

Comment: La RAE a veces impone cosas, desfigurando el idioma, y sus decisiones muchas veces son políticas.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, la forma masculina se puede usar en un tono neutral.  Por ejemplo, "Mi jefe en el trabajo es una mujer." Es más correcto que "Mi jefa en el trabajo es una mujer"; ya que con el uso de la palabra "jefa", se infiere que es una mujer.