# Uso de "poeta" en femenino

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sustantivos, género, neutralidad-de-género

Acabo de ver en el canal 24H de RTVE el siguiente titular:

> La poeta uruguaya Ida Vitale recibe el premio Cervantes.

En otros medios leo estos otros titulares:

> La poetisa uruguaya Ida Vitale recibe el Premio Cervantes 2018 a los 95 años.
>
> Los reyes entregan el Premio Cervantes a la poetisa uruguaya Ida Vitale.

Según el DLE, ambas formas ([*poeta* y *poetisa*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TUUD7eg)) están aceptadas para el femenino. Sin embargo, me gustaría saber:

- ¿Recomiendan la RAE o la Fundéu o alguna otra entidad el uso de una forma por encima de la otra?
- Si no, ¿existe alguna diferencia en cuanto a connotaciones por usar una u otra forma?

Comment: Me sonaba haberlo visto en fundéu, no recomiendan ninguna en particular, dicen esto: https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/poeta-y-poetisa-2/

Comment: Muy relacionado: [*Del término "poetisa": aceptaciones y repulsas*](https://buleria.unileon.es/handle/10612/2926), [Cómo hablan las mujeres](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=1KWioNIOm24C&oi=fnd&pg=PA7&dq=%22poetisa%22+%22poeta%22) (p.28-30), [*¿Poeta o poetisa?*](https://webs.ucm.es/info/especulo/cajetin/poetisa.html), [*Del arte de nombrar a la mujer que escribe poesía: raíces históricas y situación presente de una denominación conflictiva: la voz 'poeta' y la voz 'poesía'*](https://hera.ugr.es/tesisugr/16151446.pdf) (p.335)

Comment: Nota que esta inclusión de la palabra *poeta* con género común por la RAE es reciente - hasta la edición 1992 (o una entre 1992 y [2001](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=nNsrJ4pyVDXX22CrJCvo)) era considerada en el DLE como masculino solo.

Comment: Nota: Para saber más sobre las reglas de formación (o falta de, o cambios en) ved estar preguntas relacionadas (sobre formaciones de femeninos para distintas profesiones): [Why are both “Presidente” and “Presidenta” accepted as correct translations?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11882/5481) y [¿Se debe decir jefe o jefa al referirse a una persona de sexo femenino?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3195/5481) y [Es correcto usar la palabra “Apóstola” para referirse a una mujer que es “Apóstol”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11835/5481)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL:DR**: Ambos son válidos, pero es probable que quieras favorecer "poeta" frente a "poetisa".

No hay recomendación alguna de ninguna institución, pero parece ser que el término "poetisa" tiene ciertas **connotaciones despectivas**. He de reconocer que yo ignoraba esto por completo (para mi nunca las ha tenido. De hecho, una de las clientas del colmado de mi padre a la que yo le llevaba los recados se definía a sí misma como "poetisa". Claro, que de esto han pasado ya casi 25 años...).

Buscando un poco por la red, encontramos en esta entrada de [Escritores.org: Poeta o poetisa](https://www.escritores.org/recursos-para-escritores/articulos-de-interes/19198-poeta-o-poetisa)

> hay un debate abierto sobre estas cuestiones, ya que la lengua no es inocente y refleja convencionalismos sociales. Lo cierto es que **el femenino [poetisa] se ha empleado en ciertos tiempos de una manera peyorativa**, minusvalorando la obra, y por ello algunas poetas prefieren utilizar este término [poeta] que no crea diferencias. En el pasado se había identificado a las "poetisas" con señoritas cursis que llenaban sus ocios componiendo rimas sentimentales, es curioso que, dado que también existían varones con tal afectación que escribían poemas de menos valor, nunca se los diferenció con una palabra distinta<sup>1</sup>.

Similarmente en [¿Se dice poeta o poetisa?](http://www.estandarte.com/noticias/idioma-espanol/poetisa-o-poeta_2478.html), que comienza aclarando que la RAE considera ambas formas correctas para referirse a una mujer que escribe poesía, encontramos

> La creación del femenino de poeta como poetisa responde a la misma regla que el caso de profeta/profetisa, pero se da la circunstancia de que **la palabra poetisa ha estado cargada de tono despectivo durante mucho tiempo**.

y respaldan esta afirmación citando un artículo "publicado en La Nación, que descubrimos en la web de la Fundéu BBVA, *Cuando Safo no era poeta*", y que diría que

> “¿Por qué, **si ya teníamos poetisa, se empezó a usar poeta como femenino**? Por un reclamo feminista mal entendido. Las pobres poetisas tenían mala fama. **Se las identificaba con aquellas señoritas cursis que en otro tiempo, a falta de ocupación mejor, llenaban sus ocios componiendo rimas sentimentales**. Como si no hubiera habido varones que hacían lo mismo, se entendía que los poetas eran poetas en serio, profesionales (por así decirlo), y se despreciaba a las poetisas. Entonces l**as poetisas que no querían ser confundidas con poetisas empezaron a llamarse a sí mismas poetas**, como aquella presidenta que se hacía llamar presidente porque creía que así adquiría la autoridad que su persona no tenía (pero peor, porque la forma presidente era de género común, y poeta era solo masculina). En realidad, la reivindicación no tenía nada de feminista: era puro machismo. Pero tanto insistieron aquellas obcecadas mujeres que el uso prendió y la Academia, quizás a regañadientes, tuvo que registrarlo”

Habría otras dos menciones destacables en [Poetisa VS poeta ¿Cuál es la forma correcta?](https://www.poemas-del-alma.com/blog/especiales/poetisa-poeta-cual-forma) (que viene a decir lo mismo de que el término *poetisa* está cargado de connotaciones por "el machismo" que hace que "En algunas culturas de la antigüedad se consideraba que la mujer que componía versos lo hacía mal") y [¿Poeta o poetisa? de Soledad de Andrés Castellanos](https://webs.ucm.es/info/especulo/cajetin/poetisa.html) de la Universidad Complutense de Madrid, sobre cómo se refieren las mujeres poeta a ellas mismas y cómo se refieren los hombres poeta a sus compañeras de profesión. Entre ellas destacar el párrafo que dice:

> En los últimos años se empiezan a oír algunas voces de mujeres *feministas*, como Ana Rossetti y otras, que se llaman a sí mismas poetisas. Mantienen que, como ocurre en otros casos, lo que hay que rehabilitar es el femenino, dándole contenido y reivindicando a las buenas poetisas que ha habido y que hay, en vez de evitar una palabra como poetisa sólo porque su uso anterior la haya estigmatizado. También las palabras, sobre todo si están bien hechas y cumplen una función, tienen derecho a dignificar su contenido.

Este último artículo termina con **cuatro conclusiones** (siendo la primera de ellas la más relevante para responder a esta pregunta):

1. En el español actual es posible elegir entre el sustantivo de género común poeta y el femenino poetisa para referirse a la mujer que hace versos
2. En algunas profesiones, la diferenciación de género se marca mediante el artículo u otros determinantes: *periodista, estudiante, paciente, artista, poeta...*
3. Existe también la posibilidad para las mujeres de utilizar el masculino para la referencia a las profesiones ("el ingeniero soy yo" a la vez que "la ingeniera soy yo")
4. Durante un extenso periodo de tiempo, que [los autores del artículo de la UCM] no nos sentimos capaces de determinar con precisión, el femenino poetisa ha estado contaminado por la idea de que se evocaba con él la incapacidad y la ignorancia de muchas y, con frecuencia, su cursilería o afectación

Así que ambos términos son válidos y no hay recomendación oficial de usar uno sobre otro en ningún contexto. Sobre las connotaciones peyorativas marcadas por la sociedad sobre el término "poetisa", allá cada uno que piense lo que quiera.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Esta afirmación es falsa. En el último articulo proporcionado encontramos la mención del término "peyorativo **poetastro** [que] sigue apareciendo en las dos últimas ediciones académicas (1992 y 2001) exclusivamente como masculino, definido como ‘mal poeta’."

Comment: Cuando en la pregunta hablé de "connotaciones" no me imaginaba que fuese a ser así, pensaba que sería algo más sutil. Es curioso que pase lo mismo que con las actrices estadounidenses, que prefieren denominarse "actor" y no "actress". Genial respuesta, Diego, gracias.

Comment: Creo que tu nota a pie de página no es correcta. La connotación que el artículo menciona para *poetisa* es distinta de la que tiene *poetastro*; la primera se refiere, específicamente, a ser cursi o relamida, mientras que la segunda puede indicar cualquier cosa.

Comment: @Gorpik  la afirmación del primer artículo es que entre los poetas varones nunca hubo distinción con una palabra distinta para aquellos que "escribían poemas de menos valor". La existencia del término peyorativo exclusivamente masculino _poetastro_ indica que **sí** hay una palabra que distingue a los poetas masculinos que hacen poemas de menos valor (sin distinguir si es por cursis, por absurdos, por poco emotivos, por no conservar la rima, o por tener mala calidad en general). Otra cosa es que poetisa y poetastro no sean plenos equivalentes en sus respectivos géneros.